# Reading Buffer from Software-Serial & Writing to Serial

Tags: serial, softwareserial, arduino-micro, bytes, hid

My progress so far:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial ttySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
byte buffer;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Native USB only
  }

  Serial.println("Serial Initialized");

  //Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  ttySerial.begin(115200);
  ttySerial.println("tty Initialized");
}

void loop() 
{
  ttySerial.listen();
  while (ttySerial.available())
    //byte buffer = ttySerial.read();
    //Serial.write(buffer);
    Serial.write(ttySerial.read());


//    if (Serial.available())
//      ttySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

I am really confused because if I write the data as the as the buffer I have defined, the serial monitor goes crazy. If I upload the code as shown, I don't get anything weird in the monitor but the behavior is not what I expect.

I am writing to the software-serial on RX10 & TX11 (from javascript) the following data:
Buffer.from(`[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`) (keystroke "a")

The `Buffer.from` method comes from `node` using the `serialport` `npm` module. (This is basically irrelevant since sending the data from `Buffer.from('test')` works and is output to the monitor.

As you can see, the buffer is 1 byte (the array forming the 8 bits). Why is the buffer not read as "a" in the monitor? Is it because the Micro has an abstract HID report descriptor (see below)?

Additionally, what does `Serial.write(...)` represent? I.e. when I close the Arduino IDE serial monitor, will my Arduino Micro automatically assume its HID function and write the data as an HID device? S

I know there are already `keyboard` and `mouse` HID libraries but I already have code that generates the raw HID data that I would prefer to utilize. Note that the buffer described above comes from the HID report descriptor for a generic keyboard i.e. the "4" is not merely the ASCII code for "a". [Explained Here](https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/using-rpi-zero-as-keyboard-report-descriptor) Maybe I can use https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HID ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: 
This is the output I see from the code as shown (without the monitor "going crazy")

```
19:51:03.017 -> Serial Initialized
19:51:13.932 -> //Where I was hoping to see "a"
```

EDIT 2: I found the report descriptor in `Keyboard.cpp`:

```
  //  Keyboard
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)  // 47
    0x09, 0x06,                    // USAGE (Keyboard)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85, 0x02,                    //   REPORT_ID (2)
    0x05, 0x07,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)

  0x19, 0xe0,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)
    0x29, 0xe7,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)

  0x95, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x03,                    //   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)

  0x95, 0x06,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (6)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x73,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (115)
    0x05, 0x07,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)

  0x19, 0x00,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved (no event indicated))
    0x29, 0x73,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)
    0x81, 0x00,                    //   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
    0xc0,                          // END_COLLECTION
```

I will need to compare this to the data I would be sending to `Keyboard.write()`

Comment: you have not said what problems you are experiencing ... `serial monitor goes crazy` and `behavior is not what I expect` are both meaningless

Comment: please refer to this https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

Comment: @jsotola
`serial monitor goes crazy` - the monitor receives a ton of output that is coming so fast I can't actually see what it is saying and its continuous scrolling wont let me narrow it down.
`behavior is not what I expect` - If I turn the timestamp on I can see that data was received but it is nothing visible let alone the "a" I was hoping for

Comment: @jsotola Thanks but that is the example I used to come up with what you see above. In a sense, the software-serial works fine - it is the reading/writing I am struggling with

Comment: use a lower baud rate and you may be able to see what is flying by ... turning off the auto-scroll may also help .... otherwise, use an external serial monitor, such as *putty* and turn on file capture

Comment: @jsotola it *looks* like it is just saying "Serial Initialized" a bunch of times - yup can confirm: `19:58:43.472 -> Serial Initialized
19:58:43.555 -> ` is the continuous output

Answer (score 0):

Don't use listen() this way. It clears the receive buffer. You loose the data received before listen() call.

You have only one SoftwareSerial instance so you don't need to call listen(). The listen() function clears the receive buffer because there is only one buffer for all SoftwareSerial instances.

Comment: This did not solve my issue. I will post my output in an edit

Comment: I am thinking that the `Serial` is not sure how to parse the input buffer. I thought that it might work for a `Keyboard.write(<buffer>)` method since the report descriptor in `Keyboard.cpp` might know how to parser the buffer input - but to no avail. This was part of reason for the question "what does `Serial.write(...) represent?...`

Comment: Perhaps `HID.SendReport(uint8_t id, const void* data, int len)` might work but idk what `id`, `data`, or `len` would be exactly in this context... maybe `id` is the buffer and `len` is `8` but what would `data` be?

Comment: @SterlingButters, your code in Question doesn't initialize and use HID, so there is no HID in play and sure not over SoftwareSerial

Comment: but you think that if I initialized the HID, that buffer might work? Could you also speak to what `id`, `data`, and `len` might be in this case?

Comment: what buffer?. SoftwareSerial and HID have nothing to do one with other.

Comment: As I understand it, I am using Software Serial to collect the buffer I am transmitting to pin 10 (from js). Then I would like to write the buffer using some HID emulation library. My question is, with the buffer I have defined above, would this work and how would I specify the arguments to `HID.SendReport(...)`?

Comment: if you want to sent keyboard keys, use the Keyboard library. see the examples of the library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105124/discussion-between-sterling-butters-and-juraj).